# Kendo UI for Angular2 - Scrollview ItemChanged

Tags: angular, scrollview, kendo-ui-angular2

How do I make use of the ItemChanged Event to get the index of the current item? Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
(itemChanged)="itemChanged($event)"
```

and then

```
public itemChanged(e) {
  console.log(e.index);
}
```

Here is a plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/EdDp5vF4dLTYjt6EZWDu?p=preview